# wmctrl -- rename window title but need to select by hexadecimal window identifier

Tags: window, titlebar, wmctrl

I have two instances of a windowed program running. `wmctrl -l` shows them having identical "long names," though their hexadecimal window identities shown in the first column are different. Using:

```
wmctrl -r "oldname" -N "newname"
```

doesn't work because, well, two windows with identical names.

Entering:

```
wmctrl -r -i <hex> -N "newname"
```

throws off:

```
Cannot convert argument to number
```

I can use `:SELECT:` to manually select the window to change but I want this to run from command line.

How  can I tell `wmctrl` to use the hex identity? Thank you!